# Scrolling an image from half to full screen moving the content down

Tags: android

I want to achieve the following.When i enter the screen, an image is displayed half and the content is below the image.When i gradually scroll down the image gets displayed its other parts from half to remaining part till full image is displayed and the content is moved below.
How can this be achieved in android . Is there a third party library?
Can  the same be achieved  CollapsingToolbarLayout and how ?

Answer (score -1):

In your layout, add the following in your scroll view

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

this should do the job

Comment: thats not what i need.

Comment: my bad i misunderstood the question